# Cannot resolve directory in Angular project using Intellij IDE

Tags: angular, intellij-idea

#### file locations

`C:\Projects\project\project-front\src\assets\icon.scss`

`C:\Projects\project\project-front\src\assets\fonts\someFile.eot`

#### behaviour

I want to import someFile.eot into icon.scss.

When I use the path: `'./assets/fonts/someFile.eot'` the project compiles succesfully but intellij inspection gives the following warning:

```
Cannot resolve directory 'assets'
```

And if I use: `'../assets/fonts/someFile.eot'` I see no errors, but when I try to build the project I get the following error:

```
CssSyntaxError: C:\Projects\project\project-front\src\assets\icon.scss:7:8: Can't resolve '../assets/fonts/someFile.eot' in 'C:\Projects\project\project-front\src'
```

#### Question

How do I make sure Intellij reconizes the correct paths? Thanks in advance!

#### edit

Invalidating caches and restarting does not fix the problem

Comment: try just `assets/...`

Comment: @Andrei. This does not solve the problem. Intellij inspection is giving the same warning.

Comment: relative paths (starting with `./`) are resolved relative to current file... And `./assets/fonts/someFile.eot` can't be resolved relative to `assets\icon.scss`, thus the error. There is no way to fix this in the IDE, the error is expected. I'd suggest using absolute paths instead